# Should I use php mail function or phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Well, so far, I have been using php built in function, mail(), and I have no problems with it, even I sent a blast to 1000+ users. But then, lately I found this phpmailer, which is specially design to send email.

Q1: Should I change to this phpmailer?

Q2: What are the advantages of using phpmailer?

Q3: I found other products on phpmailer website, i.e phpmailer FE, ML etc. What are those? Which one you guys is using?

Q4: Have anyone tried sending blast email to 2000+ users with phpmailer? If yes, does it cause any problems?

Answer (score 8):

Q1: You should definitely switch away from using `mail()`

Q2: `mail()` function is really, really for simple stuff. Mail libraries hide a lot of low level stuff from the user, and offer simple ways to make HTML emails, embedded images in mail, etc.

Instead of phpmailer I'd recommend [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

- Send emails using SMTP, sendmail, postfix or a custom Transport implementation of your own
- Support servers that require username & password and/or encryption
- Protect from header injection attacks without stripping request data content
- Send MIME compliant HTML/multipart emails
- Use event-driven plugins to customize the library
- Handle large attachments and inline/embedded images with low memory use

I've used SwiftMailer to send 15000+ mails, but as you'll find in SwiftMailer documentation, its recommended to send mails in smaller batches (depends on you server ex. 100, 200, 500 per batch), using cron.

Comment: Depends on when and where the "bounce" occurs. If the MTA your swiftmailer is connected to rejects an address, yes, you can detect that. see http://swiftmailer.org/docs/finding-failures

Comment: +1 for "not using mail function and using an existing class" : existing class will already do most of the work, and will be much more tested than any code you could write => big win !

Comment: As VolkerK said if your server rejects the address you can detect that, but to detect mails that were bounced by some other server, you need to set the return address for your mail. see http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/sending/bounce_address

Comment: I see. Well, looks like there is no phpmailer supporter here, isnt it? I will definitely take a good look at the swiftmailer, thanks :)