# Encrypt PHP mail() and attachement using phpMailer

Tags: php, email, encryption, email-attachments

I have recently started using the phpMailer class for all my forms. My script still uses php's `mail();` function.
I would like to start encrypting the emails I get from the contact form and the file that is uploaded and attached from the same form.

I have been researching using `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt();` and `S/MIME` but am not sure if  **1. Either option will work in this situation** and **2. is one easier to implement**

Below is the phpMailer class script I have running now.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
echo $path_of_uploaded_file;
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "Contact Request from ".$_POST['name']." | ". $current_date;

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Who would decrypt the received message? Would you send an encryption key to the recipient?

Comment: Why? Don't understand exactly why..

Comment: @pekka we can if that is the only way to encrypt the data.

Comment: @Pekka That would be the OP: `I would like to start encrypting the emails I get from the contact form and the file that is uploaded and attached from the same form.`

Comment: @Gabriel we are conforming to guidelines that all emails containing the type of file that is attached must be encrypted.

Comment: I just found a question similar to mine that I am going to read through. Sorry I did not mean to duplicate post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003935/sending-an-e-mail-with-an-attachment-using-s-mime-php