# PhP mail function returning true but mail is not delivered

Tags: php, email

I have a domain `www.ipsmeerut.com`, i m using the script below to send mail. It is returning true but mail is not sending.

Here's my script:

```
    <?php
    $to = 'brajnacs@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Test';
    $headers = "From: Test<no-reply@ipsmeerut.com>\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
    $message = "<html><body>";
    $message .= "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    $res=false;
    $res=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    var_dump($res);
    echo "Mail sent to ".$to;
    ?>
```

This script is working fine on my other domains. `var_dump` is showing `true`. My mail server is `aspmx.l.google.com` and I have also added `MX Entry` for it.

Comment: I find PHP mailer a bit crude, have you tried using phpmailer? may help with interaction with google mail.

Comment: Best not use `mail()` at all. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231886/should-i-use-php-mail-function-or-phpmailer

Comment: yes sir i am using phpmailer class that is also not working while returning true

Answer (score 0):

Use phpmailer, Try this

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = 'you content goes here';
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just using your default MX and try testing again? dose Google allows to send anonymous email with authentication?

Comment: I am just a newbie. can you please tell me how to know our default MX

Comment: it your domain.com (ipsmeerut.com) change google MX to the default.